# FullCalendar: get new start / end times while resizing

Tags: jquery, resize, fullcalendar

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few hours now, but I can't figure out how.
I have a small popover which is displayed next to a FullCalendar (fullcalendar.io) event while resizing / dragging it and I want to display the new start / end times immediately inside it while resizing, just like it is displayed on the event itself (This is meant to be a confirm / adjust change popover). I thought it would be a very messy approach to try to use this text of the event:

```
$('.fc-helper-skeleton .fc-time > span').text()
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to do this. If FullCalendar does this by default, I assume there should be an easy way to get to these values while resizing?

It would be great if i could get the values as moment objects while resizing. Or is there a performance reason why this feature doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly supported... but there's a pretty good way of doing it.

We utilize [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) and the `start/stop drag/resize` callbacks.

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
    if(event.changing){ // If this event is being changed, grab its render date
        $("#currenttime").html("Start: "+event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mma")+"<br> End: "+event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mma"));
    }
},
eventResizeStart: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view ){
    // We can add properties to the event object
    event.changing = true; // Event is being changed
},
eventResizeEnd: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view ){
    event.changing = false; // Event is finished being changed
},
eventDragStart: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view ){
    event.changing = true;
},
eventDragEnd: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view ){
    event.changing = false;
},
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/9q8k4awa/2/)

I can't imagine any reason this wouldn't be stable. And it's quite extensible, you could go a lot of directions from here.

Note that not all events have an end date, so do a null check before using it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. It's working great and looks really clean.

Comment: I think the events have been renamed: `eventResizeEnd` to `eventResizeStop` and `eventDragEnd` to `eventDragStop`. See [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

As in `v5`, the [render hooks methods](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) replaced `eventRender` used on accepted answer.
This can now be done using the [`eventContent`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) method.

```
eventContent: function(arg) {
   if(info.isResizing || info.isDragging) {
      // Use arg.event.start and arg.event.end 
   }
}
```

You could also use this method to inject html into the event's view - an exemple is available in the method's documentation.